# Jcabi Github ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, git, exception, initializer, jcabi

I am currently working on a Bukkit plugin, and trying to implement to get config files from github. I am trying to use JCabi-Github for this. I got the library implemented and working, but whenever I use it, it creates an error. I tried to use this code:

```
Github git = new RtGitHub(user, pass);
```

1. Which doesn't give any compile-time errors
2. And following the Javadoc should be just right

But when it runs, it creates a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Check how you are using your program with JCabi-GitHub.
See [issue 1270](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github/issues/1270):

> I'm afraid that "compile via eclipse" is what broke the structure of the JAR file.
>   Try to package with Maven.

Comment: how to do that, because i have never used maven...?

Comment: @Human if there is a pom.xml, that would be enough for you to import it in Eclipse as a maven project. But if not, posting (editing your question) the stacktrace will help.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/natirasimu.xml this is my pom.xml file and this https://hastebin.com/tuqukacasu.sql is the error it gives me, just dont mind the bukkit related stuff, and i have all files from the jcabi jar in my project

Comment: Try cloning https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github and do a mvn clean install. Then go back to your project, and compile again, changing the jcabi-github dependency from 0.23 to 1.20.1

Comment: again, i have never used maven, so could you please explain what a mvn clean install is

Comment: @Human Sure: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven. With Eclipse: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html

Comment: oke i imported it, but it has an error in its pom.xml https://hastebin.com/cocolopazo.css the error is created at a <parent> tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not only "compile via eclipse". There's a bug in the library: it reads some attributes from its Manifest.MF, which may be problematic when you package your app in a .war, for instance.

There is an open ticket to change this mechanism; until then, the best solution is to:

1) use Maven to build and package your app

2) use maven-assembly-plugin to hardcode the needed values into your final artifact's Manifest.MF.

See here: https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-github/issues/1198#issuecomment-225122003